# MvvmCross биндинг кастомного свойства с кастомным вью

Tags: mvvm, binding, customview

Пытаюсь биндить свойство кастомного типа к кастомной вьюшке. В результате в биндер в метод SetValue(object value) приходит null. Почему так происходит? Возможен ли в MvvmCross биндинг такого типа?

Основная View Model:

```
public class RecipesFiltersVM : MvxViewModel
{
    public SearchField DishField { get; private set; }
    public SearchField CuisineField { get; private set; }
    public SearchField IngredientField { get; private set; }

    public RecipesFiltersVM()
    {

    }
}
```

Кастомный SearchField:

```
public class SearchField : MvxViewModel
{
    private String _searchResult;
    public String SearchResult {
        get { return _searchResult; }
        set {
            _searchResult = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => SearchResult);
            UpdateFoundFilters ();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Filter> _foundFilters;
    public ObservableCollection<Filter> FoundFilters {
        get { return _foundFilters; }
        set {
            _foundFilters = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => FoundFilters);
        }
    }
```

Кастомная вьюшка:

```
public class SearchFieldView : UIView
{
    public UITextField SearchResult { get { return _searchResult; } }
    private UITextField _searchResult;

    public UITableView FoundFilters { get { return _foundFilters; } }
    private UITableView _foundFilters;
}
```

Биндер:

```
public class SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder : MvxTargetBinding
{
    protected SearchFieldView SearchFieldView {
        get { return (SearchFieldView)Target; }
    }

    public SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder (SearchFieldView target)
        : base (target)
    {

    }

    public override void SetValue (object value)
    {
        //value always is null!
    }

    public override Type TargetType {
        get
        {
            return typeof(SearchField);
        }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode {
        get
        {
            return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;
        }
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<SearchFieldView> (
            "SearchField",
            indicators => new SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder(indicators)
        );
        base.FillTargetFactories (registry);
    }
```

Основной ViewController:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<RecipesFiltersDialog, RecipesFiltersVM>();
set.Bind (_dish).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.DishField);
set.Bind (_cuisine).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.CuisineField);
set.Bind (_ingredient).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.IngredientField);
set.Apply ();
```